# Cant Enroll/renew Certificate : Server 2008R2 as client ans Server 2019 as CA

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

I have an issue with all my 2008R2 servers, they can no longer enroll/renew certificates.
It works with windows 10 and server 2012 R2 as client.
Error is RPC not available.

From Event Viewer

> L’inscription de certificat pour Système local n’a pas pu renouveler
> un certificat GETServeurRDS avec l’ID de demande N/A  à partir de
> SERVER.domain.com\xxx-xxx-CA (Le serveur RPC n’est pas disponible.
> 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722)).
>
> - System
>
>   - Provider     [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-CertEnroll     [ Guid]
>     {54164045-7C50-4905-963F-E5BC1EEF0CCA}     [ EventSourceName]
>     CertEnroll
>   - EventID 16     [ Qualifiers]  49754

My CA is on windows server 2019. My templates are compatibles with server 2003/XP
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally do that :
Make a csr from mmc and ask for certificate with web enrollment.
I don't know what happen with server 2008 R2.